# build semi circle progress bar with round corners and shadow in java script and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, progress-bar

I searched a lot and finding nothing on it. I want to  make a progress bar with **round corners**.progress bar need to have **shadow**. All I did as of now is here :

```js
$(".progress-bar").each(function(){
  
  var bar = $(this).find(".bar");
  var val = $(this).find("span");
  var per = parseInt( val.text(), 10);

  $({p:0}).animate({p:per}, {
    duration: 3000,
    easing: "swing",
    step: function(p) {
      bar.css({
        transform: "rotate("+ (45+(p*1.8)) +"deg)"
      });
      val.text(p|0);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  background-color:#3F63D3;  
}

.progress-bar{
  position: relative;
  margin: 4px;
  float:left;
  text-align: center;
}
.barOverflow{ 
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden; 
  width: 150px; height: 70px; 
  margin-bottom: -14px;
}
.bar{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 150px; height: 150px; 
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 15px solid gray;       
  border-bottom-color: white; 
  border-right-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="barOverflow">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <span>100</span>%
</div>
```

I want to make **corners round** and having shadow. below given image represent what actually i want. Shadow is missing because i don't know to draw. :

[image]

I have tried [Progressbar.js](https://jsfiddle.net/kimmobrunfeldt/sqwdkrg0/) also, but I don't have much knowledge about SVG. Any answer would be appreciated.

Comment: you wont get the desired results using border radius - you'll need to learn SVG

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. yes i also think so. can you suggest a good tutorial ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> @jaromanda for suggestion of learning SVG.

Yes is looks very hard to achieve from border-radius. So i looked into SVG and find it pretty handy. Here is my snippet:

```js
// progressbar.js@1.0.0 version is used
// Docs: http://progressbarjs.readthedocs.org/en/1.0.0/

var bar = new ProgressBar.SemiCircle(container, {
  strokeWidth: 10,
  color: 'red',
  trailColor: '#eee',
  trailWidth: 10,
  easing: 'easeInOut',
  duration: 1400,
  svgStyle: null,
  text: {
    value: '',
    alignToBottom: false
  },
  
  // Set default step function for all animate calls
  step: (state, bar) => {
    bar.path.setAttribute('stroke', state.color);
    var value = Math.round(bar.value() * 100);
    if (value === 0) {
      bar.setText('');
    } else {
      bar.setText(value+"%");
    }

    bar.text.style.color = state.color;
  }
});
bar.text.style.fontFamily = '"Raleway", Helvetica, sans-serif';
bar.text.style.fontSize = '2rem';

bar.animate(0.45);  // Number from 0.0 to 1.0
```

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

svg {
  height: 120px;
  width: 200px;
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 10;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow( -3px -2px 5px gray );
  filter: drop-shadow( -3px -2px 5px gray );
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kimmobrunfeldt/progressbar.js/1.0.0/dist/progressbar.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,600,800,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I want to suggest some stupid but quick solution since you're already using *position: absolute*. You can add background color to the circles when your animation starts.

**html:**

```
<div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"><div class="back"></div></div>
    <div class="barOverflow">
        <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
    <span>0</span>%
</div>
```

**css:**

```
/** all your css here **/
body{
    background-color:#3F63D3;  
}

.progress-bar{
    position: relative;
    margin: 4px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
.barOverflow{ 
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden; 
    width: 150px; height: 70px; 
    margin-bottom: -14px;
}
.bar{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 150px; height: 150px; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 15px solid gray;       
    border-bottom-color: white; 
    border-right-color: white;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.progress-bar > .left {
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -4px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.progress-bar > .right {
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -4px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.back {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: gray;
    position: absolute;
}
```

**jquery:**

```
$(".progress-bar").each(function(){
    var bar = $(this).find(".bar");
    var val = $(this).find("span");
    var per = parseInt( val.text(), 10);
    var $right = $('.right');
    var $back = $('.back');

$({p:0}).animate({p:per}, {
    duration: 3000,
    step: function(p) {
        bar.css({
            transform: "rotate("+ (45+(p*1.8)) +"deg)"
        });
    val.text(p|0);
    }
}).delay( 200 );

if (per == 100) {
    $back.delay( 2600 ).animate({'top': '18px'}, 200 );
}

if (per == 0) {
    $('.left').css('background', 'gray');
}
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y86qs0a9/7/

Comment: @Deepak-Sharma, my bad, edited, jsfiddled. Now should work.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dssoft32/y86qs0a9/2/ it not working when added to progress bar

Comment: voted up for your efforts. but its not smooth at the end and i need shadow too. let know if it works

Comment: @DeepakSharma, well, you asked for corners and I did them for you. If you wanted me to polish the animation for you, that's another question, but here it is. https://jsfiddle.net/y86qs0a9/7/

Answer (score 0):

Same as the answers above, I found it much easier to implement using SVG instead of pure CSS.

However I couldn't find a single simplistic implementation using only HTML and CSS, or at least with *no libraries, no external scripts or no dependencies*. I found that given the math that needs to be calculated to make the SVG transformations to represent the percentage, JS needs to be included (if someone knows how to achieve this with only HTML and CSS I'd love to learn how). But **what the JS script does is not long or complex enough to justify the overhead of adding yet another dependency to my codebase.**

- The JS calculations are pretty easy once you read through. You need to calculate the coordinate for the end point of the gauge in the coordinate system of the SVG. so basic trig.
- Most of the CSS is not even needed and I added just to style it and to make it pretty. You can add shadow or gradients same as you could with any HTML pure shape.
- Here is the codePen https://codepen.io/naticaceres/pen/QWQeyGX

You can easily tinker with this code to achieve any kind of shape of circular gauge (full circle, lower half of the semi-circle, or any variation including ellipsis).

Hope this is helpful.

```js
// # Thanks to mxle for the first rounded corner CSS only solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/42478006/4709712
// # Thanks to Aniket Naik for the styling and the basic idea and implementation https://codepen.io/naikus/pen/BzZoLL 
//     -  Aniket Naik has a library, linked to that codepen you should check out if you don't want to copy-paste or implement yourself

// the arc radius in the meter-value needs to stay the same, and must always be x=y, not lower than the possible circle that can connect the two points (otherwise the ratio is not preserved and the curvature doesn't match the background path).
// to style the gauge, make it bigger or smaller, play with its parent element and transform scale. don't edit width and height of SVG directly
function percentageInRadians(percentage) {
  return percentage * (Math.PI / 100);
}

function setGaugeValue(gaugeElement, percentage, color) {
  const gaugeRadius = 65;
  const startingY = 70;
  const startingX = 10;

  const zeroBasedY = gaugeRadius * Math.sin(percentageInRadians(percentage));
  const y = -zeroBasedY + startingY;
  const zeroBasedX = gaugeRadius * Math.cos(percentageInRadians(percentage));
  const x = -zeroBasedX + gaugeRadius + startingX;
  // # uncomment this to log the calculations of the coordinates for the final point of the gauge value path.
  //console.log(
  //  `percentage: ${percentage}, zeroBasedY: ${zeroBasedY}, y: ${y}, zeroBasedX: ${zeroBasedX}, x: ${x}`
  //);

  gaugeElement.innerHTML = `<path d="M ${startingX} ${startingY}
           A ${gaugeRadius} ${gaugeRadius} 0 0 1 ${x} ${y}
           " stroke="${color}" stroke-width="10" stroke-linecap="round" />`;
}

percentageChangedEvent = (gauge, newPercentage, color) => {
  const percentage =
    newPercentage > 100 ? 100 : newPercentage < 0 ? 0 : newPercentage;
  setGaugeValue(gauge, percentage, color);
};

function initialGaugeSetup(gaugeElementId, inputId, meterColor, initialValue) {
  const gaugeElement = document.getElementById(gaugeElementId);
  setGaugeValue(gaugeElement, 0, meterColor);

  const inputElement = document.getElementById(inputId);

  inputElement.value = initialValue;
  setGaugeValue(gaugeElement, initialValue, meterColor);

  inputElement.addEventListener("change", (event) =>
    percentageChangedEvent(gaugeElement, event.target.value, meterColor)
  );
}

// Gauge Initial Config
initialGaugeSetup(
  "svg-graph-meter-value",
  "svg-gauge-percentage-2",
  "rgb(227 127 215)",
  40
);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #999;
  font-family: Hevletica, sans-serif;
}


/* SVG Path implementation */

.svg-container {
  margin: 20px auto 10px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 150px;
}

svg {
  fill: transparent;
}

.input-percent-container {
  text-align: center;
}

.input-percent-container>* {
  display: inline;
}

input {
  text-align: right;
  width: 40px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #5d5d5d;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-container">
  <svg width="150" height="80" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M 10 70
           A 65 65 0 1 1 140 70
           " stroke="grey" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" />
      <g id="svg-graph-meter-value">
      </g>
    </svg>
</div>
<div class="input-percent-container"><input id="svg-gauge-percentage-2" /><span>%<span/></div>
```