# How to make Semi circle progress bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar

I want to make a semi circle progress bar in my project but I don't know how t make it can anyone help me

Comment: Already answered here: [build semi circle progress bar with round corners and shadow in java script and CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477756/build-semi-circle-progress-bar-with-round-corners-and-shadow-in-java-script-and)

Comment: it also reminds me of that question , also closed missing code attempts : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36114708/how-to-make-roundable-progress-bar/36115654#36115654